# Terraform iam_policy_document - diff. of resource vs. principal

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam

I would like to ask if someone knows the difference between a "resource" and a "principal", when creating an aws_iam_policy_document in terraform.

The [terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy_document.html) has the following information:

- **resource**: A list of resource ARNs that this statement applies to. This is required by AWS if used for an IAM policy.
- **principals**: A nested configuration block (described below) specifying a resource (or resource pattern) to which this statement applies.

From reading the above two sentences, it looks like they have the same **effect**, even thought they might do different things.

On further research, I came accross [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html), which explains the differences between **identity-based** and **resource-based** policies.

It seams to me that this might be the answer to my question. If so, from what I understand, resource is a "resource-based" policy, while principal is a "identity-based" policy. Is that correct?

If this is the case, my follow-up question is: can I can use both type of policies together to further restrict the access?

For example, if i have a resource policy on an S3 bucket granting complete public access, but than I add a identity-based policy for a single user, does this user become the only one who can access the bucket?

I appreciate your help, and will try to clarify anything that might be unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The Terraform documentation on this is a bit confusing. Prefer the AWS docs in this case. However, when TF refers to *Principal*, they do mean the same thing, i.e. **who** gets permissions. Who can be users, groups, roles and services.

*However*, a Principal isn't needed when you have a policy attached to an IAM user, group or role, because the user, group or role is the implied principal.

So why or when would you need a principal section? When the policy is attached to something that isn't inherently a user, group or role. For example, an S3 bucket policy.

HTH!